# MonoTouch: DataProtection: how to programmatically find out, whether Passcode Lock is set?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a chance to check for this additional protection of the device?

Would like to warn users, if only ordinary DataProtection
(without passcode) is set on their devices.

Thanks,
Dilettanto

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any API (MonoTouch or native iOS) that will allow you to determine this.

Comment: Would be nice though - i don't want the code - just the information, whether there is one set :-)